# Row excluded due to JOIN ON statement- Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I have a query that pulls amounts from two different tables (invoiced, paid) but a row is excluded because there is no data for the month of march in the invoice table but it is present in paid table.

How can i modify this so that the month of march is brought in with the invoiced value blank or null and paid amount populated with the amount.

```
SELECT INV.YEAR, INV.MONTH, INV.CATEGORY, INV.INV_AMT AS INV_AMT,  PAY.PAID AS PAID

FROM (
SELECT YEAR, to_char(INV_date, 'Month') AS MONTH, CATEGORY, SUM(INV_AMT) AS INV_AMT
FROM INV
WHERE DATE > '01-JAN-2020' AND CATEGORY = 'Insurance'
group by YEAR, to_char(co_date, 'Month'), CATEGORY ) INV

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT YEAR,  to_char(Pay_date, 'Month') AS MONTH, CATEGORY, SUM(PAID) AS PAID
FROM PAY
group by YEAR, to_char(Pay_date, 'Month'), CATEGORY) PAY
ON PAY.YEAR = INV.YEAR AND INV.MONTH = INV.MONTH AND PAY.CATEGORY = INV.CATEGORY
```

INVOICE TABLE:

```
YEAR    MONTH       CATEGORY      INV_AMT 
2020    February    Insurance    $670.00 
2020    January     Insurance    $2,887.00
```

PAID TABLE:

```
YEAR    MONTH       CATEGORY       PAID 
2020    March       Insurance    $5,400.00 
2020    February    Insurance    $2,953.00 
2020    January     Insurance    $5,831.00
```

Current Result:

```
YEAR    MONTH   CATEGORY         INV_AMT        PAID 
2020    February    Insurance    $670.00        $2,953.00 
2020    January     Insurance    $2,887.00     $5,831.00
```

Expected Result:

```
YEAR    MONTH   CATEGORY         INV_AMT        PAID 
2020    March       Insurance                  $5,400.00 
2020    February    Insurance    $670.00        $2,953.00 
2020    January     Insurance    $2,887.00     $5,831.00
```

Comment: `...LEFT JOIN YEAR,  to_char(...` -- That's not valid SQL.

Comment: I think he missed a SELECT there 
... LEFT JOIN ( SELECT YEAR, to_char(...

Comment: That SQL is all over the place.

Comment: its fixed guys, just missed the select

Answer (score 1):

You should use RIGHT JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN or even better try FULL OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT INV.YEAR, INV.MONTH, INV.CATEGORY, INV.INV_AMT AS INV_AMT,  PAY.PAID AS PAID

FROM (
SELECT YEAR, to_char(INV_date, 'Month') AS MONTH, CATEGORY, SUM(INV_AMT) AS INV_AMT
FROM INV
WHERE DATE > '01-JAN-2020' AND CATEGORY = 'Insurance'
group by YEAR, to_char(co_date, 'Month'), CATEGORY ) INV

FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT YEAR,  to_char(Pay_date, 'Month') AS MONTH, CATEGORY, SUM(PAID) AS PAID
FROM PAY
group by YEAR, to_char(Pay_date, 'Month'), CATEGORY) PAY
ON PAY.YEAR = INV.YEAR AND INV.MONTH = INV.MONTH AND PAY.CATEGORY = INV.CATEGORY
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on sample data you posted; sort is just for prettier display, you'd use your own.

```
SQL> with
  2  invoice (year, month, category, inv_amt) as
  3    (select 2020, 'feb', 'insurance', 670 from dual union all
  4     select 2020, 'jan', 'insurance', 2887 from dual
  5    ),
  6  paid (year, month, category, paid) as
  7    (select 2020, 'mar', 'insurance', 5400 from dual union all
  8     select 2020, 'feb', 'insurance', 2953 from dual union all
  9     select 2020, 'jan', 'insurance', 5831 from dual
 10    )
 11  select p.year, p.month, p.category, i.inv_amt, p.paid
 12  from paid p left join invoice i on i.year = p.year
 13    and i.month = p.month
 14  order by decode(p.month, 'mar', 1, 'feb', 2, 'jan', 3);

      YEAR MON CATEGORY     INV_AMT       PAID
---------- --- --------- ---------- ----------
      2020 mar insurance                  5400
      2020 feb insurance        670       2953
      2020 jan insurance       2887       5831

SQL>
```

Comment: this works in this case because theres no other category in the data sample but if you look in my join i am joining on the category as well. Thats where the issue is.

Comment: This works in case you posted, that's correct. If there's something with "category", please, edit sample data so that it reflects what you are saying. I'm having difficulties in fixing something I can't see.